# multiple-value url.Parse() in single-value context (net/url)

Tags: go

I am trying to build a simple router in Go.

As I understand it url.Parse returns both an error and the parsed url, despite including both these in the assignment I am still getting the error in the title of this question

```
func (router *Router) Get(urlString string, callback func(Res, Req)) {
    parsedUrl, err := *url.Parse(urlString)

    router.Methods["GET"][parsedUrl] = callback
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `*` in `*url.Parse(urlString)`. See http://play.golang.org/p/xa8CcENI5g

Comment: funny you say that, I actually just tried this before reading the comment. It did lose the error mentioned above, but now at runtime, when the function executes I am getting "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine"

Comment: That's going to be elsewhere in your code. It should give you a line number. Try adding the code around that to your question , or submitting a new question with that code.

Comment: Apologies, you're right I've narrowed it down to a different function. Feel free to leave the above as an answer and ill tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `*` in `*url.Parse(urlString)`.

```
func (router *Router) Get(urlString string, callback func(Res, Req)) {
    parsedUrl, err := url.Parse(urlString)

    router.Methods["GET"][parsedUrl] = callback
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/xa8CcENI5g)

Also, as the `url.Parse()` function returns an error, your `Get()` function should do something with it (preferably return it, but otherwise log it, panic etc.)